# Is it possible to return only the desired objects in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

I have two entities

Book 
- attributes: name, desc
- relationship: book with type To Many to BookLang (inverse: bookLang)

BookLang
- attributes: nameLang, descLang, lang
- relationship: bookLang with type To One to Book (inverse: book)

In BookLang there is two objects for fr,de language
If I use

```
let lang = "fr"
let pre = NSPredicate(format: "book.lang == %@", lang);
Then I have to loop through the fetchResult and then loop through the book NSSet

for b in bookSet {

    let lan = b.valueForKey("lang") as! String
        if(lan == lang){
        let name = b.valueForKey("nameLang") as! String
        println(name) // the book title in french
        break;
    }                  

}
```

How I can get in the book NSSet only the object I want

I try with

```
let subPre = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(BookLang, $s, $s.lang == %@)", lang);
```

with error

```
Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(BookLang, $s, $s.lang == %@)"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. Relationships, loops, subqueries - all unnecessary!

How about a simple string attribute `lang`?

```
let frenchBooks = allBooks.filteredSetUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "lang = %@", "fr"))
```

Or, in true Swift fashion

```
let frenchBooks = allBooks.filter() { $0.lang = "fr" }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't know about filteredSetUsingPredicate. By the way how I can make this query to work let predicateLang = NSPredicate(format: "ANY book.lang =[cd] %@ AND book.nameLang contains [c] %@", "fr", "someString"). I'm searching for given string in nameLang and with lang = fr, this should return false, but it doesn't

Comment: You are forgetting that `nameLang` is obsolete. `NSPredicate(format:"lang = 'fr' && name contains[cd] %@", searchString)`.

Comment: This can't work because lang is part of the BookLang. I'm using ANY book.lang =[cd] %@ AND book.nameLang contains [cd] %@ but then I have to filter the returned set

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating a predicate without using?
To get all the books that respect a condition you can use a fetch request against your core data context.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book") //supposing that you managed object subclass is named Book
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lang == %@", lang);
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Book] {
//DO what you want
    }
```

This is just a snippet you should complete with error and the else statement